# Another Danger font not showing on iOS but shows on Android and windows

Tags: css, sass, fonts

For the life of me I can't get another danger font to work on iOS. It works on all other devices.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Another Danger";
src: local('Another Danger'), url('../fonts/Another-Danger.ttf') format('truetype');
font-display: swap;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 400;
font-stretch: normal;}
```

Am I doing something wrong?